# Se puede crear una pequeña extensión para Chrome local?

Tags: javascript, html5, extensión-google-chrome

estoy ejecutando un codigo Javascript en un sitio web que uso habitualmente para eliminar algunas cosas que no son relevantes para mi y le cambio estilos, saco algunas cuentas, etc.

las URL de las páginas que cambio tienen el formato: https://www.sitio.com/directorio/123456

Entonces primero selecciono CIERTAS OPCIONES que son individuales en cada página y luego abro la consola y ejecuto mi código.

Por todo esto creo que me conviene crear una extensión que cada vez que se abra una URL que contenga "https://www.sitio.com/directorio/" se cree un botón en cierta parte y que tocando ese botón se ejecute cierto código de la extensión, es decir NO al cargar la pagina sino después porque antes debo seleccionar opciones que son por cada pagina.

Bueno por lo poco que entiendo de extensiones quería saber si hay alguna plantilla de extensión para hacer esto, y si yo podría usar una extensión (para Google Chrome) solo en loca, sin subirla al sitio de extensiones de Google, porque la verdad sería inútil para otros creo.

Bueno también pienso que quizás ya haya alguna otra extensión con la que se pueda hacer esta tarea, es decir alguna a la que solo haya que pegarle el código a ejecutar en ciertas URLs, si saben de alguna agradezco la info.

Comment: Lo que estás buscando es [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias extensiones que te pueden servir para ese propósito como javascript injection que puedes descargar desde chrome web store, este plugin te permite cargar tu código javascript, jquery, etc. y es posible crear reglas personalizadas para el dominio principal y los subdominios.
Saludos!

Comment: preguntas basadas en opiniones no se deben responder